# Angular: Multiple nested FormGroups in Component

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I'm trying to nest several FormGroups, which works very well if I do not want to outsource the template to own components.

Here is an example, that works

> Template

```
<form [formGroup]="baseForm">
  <div formGroupName="nestedForm1">
    <div formGroupName="nestedForm2">
      <input formControlName="nestedControl">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Typescript

```
this.baseForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  nestedForm1: this.formBuilder.group({
    nestedForm2: this.formBuilder.group({
      nestedControl: ["Default Value"]
    })
  })
});
```

If I try to outsource the "nestedForm1" and "nestedForm2" into a separate component, it does not work anymore from the second level.

An example can be found at the following link. There you can try both ways by commenting out the respective code parts in the "app.component.html"

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnpw24?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `ControlContainer` provider can be registered on any of these directives:

**Template driven directives**

- NgForm
- NgModelGroup,

**Reactive directives**

- FormGroupDirective
- FormGroupName
- FormArrayName

but you expect that it will be always `FormGroupDirective` while in the second component parent `ControlContainer` is `FormGroupName`.

I would use common solution which will work regardless type of parent `ControlContainer`:

```
viewProviders: [{
  provide: ControlContainer,
  useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
  deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
}]
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvqtis?file=src/app/nested1.component.ts)**

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you for this quick answer :-D

Comment: How to get it working when each nested form group is defined in component?

Comment: @maxlego Can you provide an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwiq87. as you can see nestedForm1 is null

Comment: @maxlego Option 1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7znw8?file=src/app/nested1.component.ts Option 2 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbkqg2?file=src/app/nested1.component.ts